# Trying to get a full list of photos in DCIM folder

Tags: java, android-camera

I have tried couple of ways to access the folder:
1)

```
File dcimDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString());
```

2. more direct

   File ais = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   String mpath = ais.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera";
   File pdir = new File(mpath);

But either way,

```
fileList = pdir.listFiles();
```

is returning zero files when there are in fact many pictures in the phone. I have verified this several ways including over FTP.

mpath above evaluates to /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera.
When I tried to access /Music, it returns proper list of files.
I also tried /Notifications and it also works.
So, it seems certain folders are returning empty.
I am not getting any exceptions since the app has specified

Any ideas why only certain folders (in particular, /DCIM/Camera) is returning empty?

Answer (score 0):

OK, stumbled into the solution: as suspected, it had to do with permissions. Despite the fact that my test app had the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, on the phone the app had no such permission, Files and media. I had to manually do it. During the initial install via Android Studio, there was no prompt for permission and at run time, the app received no errors or exceptions. Just empty folder contents which were very misleading and confusing, to say the least.

And at some point during further debugging, the permission was removed and I had to grant it manually once again. I don't exactly know which to blame: Android 12 or Android Studio.